# Enum and Array Access in Obj-C/Swift Hybrid

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, swift, enums

I have inherited a project that is on its way to become a Swift/Obj-C hybrid as per requirement. Most of the Obj-C code is so modular, that this works fine with one exception. There are hundreds of lines of definitions in the headers files as seen below:

```
enum _decks { kOneDecks = 1, kTwoDecks, kThreeDecks ...
enum _cards { kAce = 0, kKing, kQueen, kJack, ...

static const int _stackA[kFourDecks][kTwoDecks] = {

/*_evalIndex_32*/ {kAce, kAce, kAce, kAce, kKing, kKing, kKing, kKing, -1, -1, -1, -1},
/* _evalIndex_31, 7*/ {kAce, kAce, kAce, kAce, kQueen, kQueen, kQueen, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1},
...
```

Arrays like _stackA get accessed in Obj-C directly:

```
NSInteger newCard = _stackA[kQueen][random()];
```

I need to access these enums and arrays in Swift as well and can't seem to find an efficient way of doing so.  What is making things difficult is that all constants (i.e. kAce) have to remain in place for easy editing, so formatting these arrays into a plist will not work. Even worse - several of the Obj-C classes rely on those constants.

One approach I have come up with is to format the header files as json while replacing all constants with strings. I can then import and parse the json files and format the strings back into the integer arrays they were initially. But - that approach seems ridiculously complex and would result in code duplication. I'd be real happy about any tips or hints.

Comment: Here you have C-Arrays & enums. Both are not directly imported to swift. Enums can be imported using NS_ENUM macro. But C-Arrays are imported as `UnsafePointer`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `NS_ENUM` macro to use ObjC enums in Swift. Something like below:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Decks) {
    kOneDecks = 1,
    kTwoDecks,
    kThreeDecks,
};
```

And the you can use it like `Decks.OneDecks` in your Swift file.